Chrome Extension Manifest V3: Service Worker registration fails with 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extensionId')
I’m developing a Chrome extension using Manifest V3. I’m encountering the following error in the logs:
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extensionId')"
This error shows up when I try to access the service worker view in the Chrome Extensions Inspect page, but it’s not working. The service workers of other extensions work fine.
Context:

I’m using Manifest V3 and have configured a service worker in the background.js file.
For more context this is my background.js:

    console.log("Background script loaded.");
    const { OpenAI } = require("openai");  


    const openai = new OpenAI({_
        apiKey: "my_api_key"
    });

    async function generateResponse(emailContent, style) {
        try {
            const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
                model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                messages: [
                    { role: "system", content: `You are a helpful assistant. Respond in a ${style} tone.` },
                    { role: "user", content: emailContent },
                ],
            });
            
            return response.choices[0]?.message?.content || "No se pudo generar una respuesta.";
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error al contactar con OpenAI:", error);
            return "Hubo un error al contactar con OpenAI.";
        }
    }

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
        console.log("Mensaje recibido en background.js:", message); 
        if (message.type === "generateResponse") {
            console.log("Respuesta generada recibida:", message.response); 
            generateResponse(message.emailContent, message.style)
                .then(response => {
                    // Enviar la respuesta generada de vuelta a content.js
                    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
                        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { 
                            type: "generateResponse", 
                            response: response 
                        });
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err);
                    sendResponse("Hubo un error al generar la respuesta.");
                });
        }
    });  


My 'manifest.json' file looks like this:

    {
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "name": "My Extension",
      "version": "1.0",
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "storage"
      ],
      "host_permissions": [
        "https://mail.google.com/*",
        "https://api.openai.com/*"
      ],
      "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },
      "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ]
    }

Error:
In the Chrome Extensions console logs, I see the following error:
Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15
What I’ve tried:
I’ve checked that the background.js file is correctly configured. (I think it is)
I’ve updated Google Chrome to the latest version.
I’ve tried disabling other extensions that might be interfering, but the error persists.
I’ve inspected the code, but I can’t find any obvious issues with the setup.
I'm expecting at least see the logs in my background.js like:
console.log("Background script loaded.");
But I can't see it. I can see the logs in my content.js
When I click in a botton I would like see this first line of log in my background.js
Has anyone encountered this issue or knows how to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The error means that your background.js has something like foo.extensionId where foo is null or undefined.

Thanks for your reply, but I don't see anything like that in my background.js, maybe I should have it? (I'm new to js)
